# Decoding and Encoding using BASE64 in java

Tags: java, encoding

I am encountering erroneous results while trying to encode and decode a string read from a file on disk.

I am using the following code to decode and then encode :

```
byte[] word_bytes = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(word); //word is string variable

String tempStr = new BASE64Encoder().encode(word_bytes);
```

On the basis of this code, I was expecting that if I print "word" and "tempStr", I should see the same result. However, the values are different.

For example, if word = "hi!", then tempStr = "hi//" and all single letter words get converted to null values. For example, if word = "a", then tempStr = "".

The file on disk is in `UTF-8` encoding.

It would be very helpful if someone can explain the cause of this error.

sorry if this is very basic question, I don't have much prior experience with encoding formats.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your encoding/decoding backwards

Base64 is a way to turn a byte array into a String that can easily be passed around without messing up the byte encoding.

Therefore you *encode* a byte array into a String and then *decode* it back into a byte array

If you switch the order of your encoding and decoding

```
     String tempStr = new BASE64Encoder().encode("hi".getBytes());

     byte[] word_bytes = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(tempStr);

     System.out.println(tempStr);
     System.out.println(new String(word_bytes));
```

It will print this:

```
aGk=
hi
```

It also appears you are using the `sun` Base64 classes which is not a good idea.  Those are internal classes and there is no guarantee that they will be around in a future version of java or that they are present in all Java implementations.

If you are using Java 8, you can use the new `java.util.Base64` class [javadoc here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) and if you are on pre Java 8 you should use a  3rd party library which has Base64 classes instead.

Comment: `hi.getBytes()` and `new String(word_bytes)` should really be `hi.getBytes("utf-8")` and `new String(word_bytes, "utf-8")` (or choose some other encoding). otherwise the behavior is dependent on the default character encoding of the system.

Comment: thanks dkatzel! understood the issue, its working fine fore me.